# Navigating to Different Views/Screens in ReactJS onClick()

Tags: reactjs, onclick, react-router

I'm trying to create three screens, or views, for my ReactJS trivia app. The trivia app consumes an API and then manipulates that response's data, after `onClick()` events:

1. `/home` `onClick()` = redirect to /quiz
2. `/quiz`
3. `/results` Results displayed & `'Try Again' button` redirects to `/home`

**Desired application flow:** 
I want to start on `/home` screen. After clicking the `/home` screen's `'Begin' button` the user is redirected to the `/quiz` - where the quiz begins presenting a fixed number of questions to the user, one at a time. After all questions have been answered, there will be a redirect/routing to the `/results` screen. Here the user will be presented with their score, and their completed list of questions with correct/incorrect. The clicked `'Try Again' button` redirects to `/home` & restarts the quiz app.

At this point, I've looked at several potential ways of doing this, but nothing seems to be what I'm looking for. react-router doesn't seem to be capable of navigation without those Navigation links.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start 

https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

This is the API call `ComponentDidMount()` followed by a list of questions (as I'd like `/results` to appear: 

https://codesandbox.io/s/fetch-opentdb-trivia-cvl0g

Does this mean I need to use NodeJS + Express to serve/navigate to each one of these views? Is there a way I can work around react-router for navigation? Could I just update/display items in the DOM, based on state, after events? Do lifecycle methods have anything to do with a possible solution? Please help!

```js
// react-router demo mimics the functionality I want: <a href="https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-4ifp7"/>
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function BasicRouterExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">HomeCard</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/quiz">QuizCard</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/results">ResultsCard</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <hr />

        <Route exact path="/" component={HomeCard} />
        <Route path="/quiz" component={QuizCard} />
        <Route path="/results" component={ResultsCard} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function HomeCard() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Welcome to Trivia Challenge!</h2>
      <h3>You'll be presented with 10 True or False questions</h3>
      <button>BEGIN</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function QuizCard() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>QUIZ screen</h2>
      <h3>Questions text goes here</h3>
      <button>True</button>
      <button>False</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function ResultsCard() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>RESULTS: 3/5 Correct Answers</h2>
      <h3>question 1...CORRECT</h3>
      <h3>question 2...CORRECT</h3>
      <h3>question 3...INCORRECT</h3>
      <h3>question 2...CORRECT</h3>
      <h3>question 2...INCORRECT</h3>
    </div>
  );
}

export default BasicRouterExample;
```

BasicRouterExample: Using react-router I don't see how I can attach onClick() events to `buttons` & remove the SPA-styled nav links (HomeCard, QuizCard,ResultsCard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `history` from your component's props to navigate to other route `onClick`. For example

```
this.props.history.push('/quiz');
```

Comment: Thank you, Tien! I'll give this a shot